# Need help identifying a PTC thermistor in a multimeter

Tags: identification, multimeter, ptc

I have a Pro'sKit MT-1232 multimeter that has a problem with the AC voltage test.

I've been testing its components and the PTC on its input is the only component that changes the number on the display when touched and may be broken (I think).

I've searched for its code on the internet but found nothing.

So can you guys please help me find this PTC? In case you had the same problem with Pro'sKit multimeter and you know a way to fix it, please let me know.

[image: ptc Image]

Comment: That's very unlikely to be the problem... Thermistors don't usually fail unless there's a gross overload, and that would be obvious if there was.

Comment: The right leg of PTC looks cracked. If it's not, check solder joints.

Comment: A PTC (positive temperature coefficient) component is expected to change in value when you touch it because you make it warmer. If anything, your test shows that it is not faulty. What exactly is the problem with the AC voltage test?

Comment: Most likely issue with a multimeter (other than battery) is a fuse, after that the rotary switch (dirty, not making contact, screw that has come loose).

Comment: It's hard to tell from that angle, but the plated-through-holes for that part don't seem like they're properly wetted with solder. By touching it, are you perhaps making a better connection to the board?

Comment: guys i saw something about using thermistor in input as a fuse and that's why i asked this,the right leg is cracked,ac voltage problem is showing 3 volt instead of 220 and after a little touch it goes up,the welding is fine(it's a double side pcb)

Comment: Nitpick: There's no welding involved. Soldering is a very different process than welding.